# how to get address by passing latlong using google map in flex

Tags: apache-flex

when a marker is drag on google map we can get the latlong right.But i wanna get the location 
name whenever i drag the marker,so how can i get it can anyone help me?

regards 
vinit

Answer (score 2):

You should use reverse geocoding for that :) I haven't done it in flash, only asp.net, but I found an example that implements this:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api-for-flash/browse_thread/thread/b6c5d13f06e6879b